# Arch Linux no IP after initial boot

Tags: networking, arch-linux

After reboot fresh install of Arch Linux had no internet connectivity.  Some looking around showed the solution was:

```
1  # ping -c 4 8.8.8.8  (not found)
2  # ip a  (to find my devise name, in my case: ens33)
3  # systemctl enable dhcpcd@ens33
4  # ip link set ens33 up
5  # ping -c 4 8.8.8.8  (still no joy)
6  # reboot now
7  # ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 (success!!)
```

My question is how do I get rid of that reboot now (line 6)?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You enabled dhcpcd service, but didn't restart it. It was restarted on boot.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Could you remind me the command I should use?  something like `# systemctl restart dhcpcd  `?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You got it! =)

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly enabled the systemd service by doing `systemctl enable dhcpcd@ens33`. This makes the service run on boot. That's why it works when you reboot your system.

You should do `systemctl restart dhcpcd@ens33` to get the service running straight away.